# create c# object from json

Tags: c#, json

I have the following classes

```cs
    class Configuration
    {
        
        public IConverter converter { get; set; }

    }


    public class HtmlConverter : IConverter
    {
        public string Convert()
        {
            return "HTML Convertter";
        }
    }

    public class JsonConverter : IConverter
    {
        public string Convert()
        {
            return "json Convertter";
        }
    }

    public interface IConverter
    {
        string Convert();
    }
```

and myjson file is

```json
{
  "Configuration": {
    "Converter": "HtmlConverter"
  }
}
```

from the JSON file, I want to create the Configuration object.

in json file if converter is set to `"HtmlConverter"` then the `HtmlConvert` object should be created and if `"JsonConverter"` is set then `JsonConverter` object should be created.

```
Configuration  config = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Configuration>(jsonString);
```

Comment: Your JSON root object has a property "Configuration", your root C# class (`Configuration`) only has a property "Converter" (which doesn't exist in your JSON's root object).

Comment: You will need to write your own Json.NET contract-resolver to implement this logic.

Comment: Easiest way to create a converter for a simple file like yours is creating a new class and then copying the json string to the clipboard and then go to "paste" -> "as json class" in visual studio. VS will then create a model which can easily be serialized without any more implementation

Answer (score 1):

I think here you need to use some factory patterns. For example, your class **Configuration** can be like this

```
public class Configuration
{
    public string Convertor { get; set; }
    public IConverter Create()
    {
        IConverter instance = (IConverter)Activator.CreateInstance("MyAssembly", $"MyNamespace.{Convertor}").Unwrap();
        if (instance == null)
        {
            throw new Exception("Convertor not found");
        }
        return instance;
    }

}
```

And you will use this in this way.

```
Configuration config = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Configuration>(jsonString);
var converter = config.Create();
```

But If you do not want to use reflection, you can use some if/else or switch statements. But the main idea is to use factory patterns.

Also your json file should look like this

```
{
   "Convertor": "JsonConverter"
}
```